# LSTM input_shape incompatible

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to build a sequential model using Keras with an LSTM layer as the first layer. `train_x` has a shape of (21000, 2) and I'm using a batch size of 10

When I try

```
 model = Sequential()
 model.add(LSTM(128, activation='relu', input_shape=(
        train_x.shape[1:]), return_sequences=True))
```

I get an error saying

> Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_1: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2

Then I tried to change `input_shape` and set it to `input_shape=(train_x.shape)` and I got another error saying

> Error when checking input: expected lstm_1_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (21000, 2)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: ninesalt, Please check sol now i updated, and sorry for the confusion i created.

Comment: You need to have a clear understanding of what your data is. What you consieder a "sequence", and what each dimension of your data means, what do you want to extract from it. Without this, it's impossible to help.

Comment: @danielmoller The input data is just an (N, 2) dataframe with numbers. I'm not sure if that's what you mean by sequence

Comment: Well... just a dataframe is not enough to determine how to use data into an LSTM, you must have "examples", "time steps" and "features". That's why you need to "understand" the data and have an idea of what do you want to extract.

Answer (score 0):

Keras LSTM layer expects the input to be `3` dims as `(batch_size, seq_length, input_dims)`, but you have assigned it wrong. Try this

```
input_dims = train_x.shape[1]
seq_length = #decide an integer
model = Sequential()
 model.add(LSTM(128, activation='relu', input_shape=(seq_length, input_dims), return_sequences=True))
```

Also you need to reshape your data to three dims, where new dims will represent the sequence, as

I used toy dataset to show an example, here data and labels are of shape `((150, 4), (150,))` initially, using the following script:

```
seq_length = 10
dataX = []
dataY = []
for i in range(0, 150 - seq_length, 1):
    dataX.append(data[i:i+seq_length])
    dataY.append(labels[i+seq_length-1])
import numpy as np
dataX = np.reshape(dataX, (-1, seq_length, 4))
dataY = np.reshape(dataY, (-1, 1))
# dataX.shape, dataY.shape
```

Output: `((140, 10, 4), (140, 1))`

Now you can safely feed it to model.

Note: I prepared dataset for `many-to-one` model, but you can use it appropriately.

Comment: To be more precise, `RNN` layers expect the input to be 3 dimensional: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/recurrent.py#L418

Comment: Does seq length have to be a tuple? You have 10 in a comment.

Comment: Third, we don't have to specify, it will fill it with `batch_size` at training time.

Comment: No, it is not tuple, i just write it. It is integer, you can select it by  your own.

Comment: Your code is not working for me. `Error converting shape to a TensorShape: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'tuple'`

Comment: You must use tuple, it should be integer.

Comment: Can you tell, where this error arise? please add complete code, you are trying, so i give solution accordingly

Comment: `(BATCHSIZE, input_dim) == (10, (2,))`

Comment: Sorry, for mistake. I have edited it. it should be (10, 2)

Comment: Are you sure the reshape is correct? I'm getting another error saying the inputs and targets are not the same size now. `Found 2100 input samples and 21000 target samples.`

Comment: i will probably add another verified solution

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand how to apply your code to my current situation